# Is this the correct way to do a Weighted Avg?

Tags: t-sql

Here's the initial query that I needed to make certain fields a weighted average based on the field KLA as the weight.  KLA is a varchar field.

```
select  eer.Market,    
    eer.KLA,
    eer.Term,
    case  scdesc when 'ics' then 'Act' else eer.ScDesc end as ScDesc,   
    eer.Term As Term_Anual,    
    eer.VaMonths,    
        eer.RentPrice,    
        eer.BuyPrice,          
    eer.TransactionID
from View1 eer
WHERE ((@Term = 'Long Term' and Term_Anual > 11)    
  OR (@Term = 'Short Term' and Term_Anual < 12))    
  and (ArchiveID in (@ArchiveID))
order by eer.market,
     eer.KLA,
     eer.ScDesc
```

This is my first attempt ever to do a weighted average so there are a few things I'm not sure of.

So what I did is try to create a CTE by using a join.

```
SELECT  [base].Market,
    [base].MSA,
    [base].ArchiveID,
    [base].TransactionID
    [base].ScDesc,
    SUM([base].KLA) * [weighted].KLA / SUM([weighted].KLA) as KLA,
    SUM([base].VaMonths) * [weighted].VaMonths / SUM([weighted].VaMonths) as VaMonths,
    SUM([base].RentPrice) * [weighted].RentPrice / SUM([weighted].RentPrice) as RentPrice,
    SUM([base].BuyPrice) * [weighted].BuyPrice / SUM([weighted].BuyPrice) as BuyPrice       
FROM View1 [base]
INNER JOIN
(
    select  eer.Market,    
        eer.KLA,
        eer.Term,
        case  scdesc when 'ics' then 'Act' else eer.ScDesc end as ScDesc,   
        eer.Term As Term_Anual,    
        eer.VaMonths,    
            eer.RentPrice,    
            eer.BuyPrice,          
        eer.TransactionID
from View2 eer
WHERE((@Term = 'Long Term' and Term_Anual > 11)    
  OR (@Term = 'Short Term' and Term_Anual < 12))    
  and (ArchiveID in (@ArchiveID))
order by eer.market,
     eer.KLA,
     eer.ScDesc
) as [weighted]
```

Also, I don't know where I should or if I should group by KLA in the two queries I guess to get the weight either.

So does this look right in terms of trying to make some of the fields (the ones with SUM) weighted?

I need some hand holding first time through as I'm not confident I am sure I'm doing this right.  The sums are being done in fields that are money, numeric, etc. type of fields so don't worry about if they're a proper field type.  The rest of the fields that are [base]. are not weighted, I don't want those weighted obviously so selecting them straight up in my outer query.

Comment: You'll need to extract your problem out of the code above because it doesn't really make sense. Try making a simple example in excel or so and translate that to your db once you manage to get a working system out of it. If you'd still end up stuck and want to come back here then give us an example to play with that has an example table and example values; not just a vague query as we don't have any clue here what any of those fields might be! 
Also, how can a varchar field imply the weight ?

Comment: The short answer is no, on the face of it this does not look right, but as deroby pointed out, it is not clear what you are trying to do, so if you can state that in english, we can tell you if your code matches.

The usual definition for a weighted average is sum(value * weight)/sum(weight)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by some in the comments, your question is not particularly clear, but if you have some `Value` and `Weight` values in a table:

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE (
    Value DECIMAL(3,2),
    [Weight] DECIMAL(3,2)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
SELECT 6, 3
UNION
SELECT 4, 1
UNION
SELECT 9, 1
UNION
SELECT 5, 6
UNION
SELECT 3, 1
UNION
SELECT 1, 1
UNION
SELECT 3, 2
UNION
SELECT 4, 1
```

You can return the average (mean) and weighted average as follows:

```
SELECT  AVG(Value) AS Mean,
        AVG(Value * [Weight]) AS WeightedMean
FROM @SampleData
```